# Number of expected pairs of ones in a series of binary(one or zero) events

Tags: probability

1. You are given a series of binary events (1 or 0), with each event being 1 with probability P and 0 with probability (1-P). Ex. 10010110010110011110010101110010...
2. Reading from left to right, every time a '1' shows up two times in a row, this counts as a "pair". For example,
   0010**11**010**1111**010**11**10 contains four pairs by this definition (Bolded). Note that we're not counting two pairs for the rightmost pair. '01110' will only ever be one pair since we're reading left to right.
3. Given a series of length L, how many pairs will we expect to get? In the limit as L approaches infinity, what is the proportion of pairs to L?

I tried a couple ways to solve it, with two answers (neither of which are correct).

1. I tried looking at it event by event - that is, does this event make a pair. The probability of the current event $E_n$ being one is P. The odds of the previous event $E_{n-1}$ being one is also P. Naively, this would yield a 25% rate of this event making a pair. However, I consider that the previous event being 1 does not necessarily mean this is a pair - IE. If $E_{n-2}$ and $E_{n-1}$ are 1 then this is not a pair since the previous two made a pair. So we can consider 8 cases...

   000  {0}
   001  {0}
   010  {0}
   011  {1}
   100  {0}
   101  {0}
   110  {1}
   111  {?}

   where the three numbers are $E_{n-2}, E_{n-1},E_n$  Then a fourth number for  {This event makes a pair?}. We have two definite pairs, but $111%$ poses a conundrum since it could have been $0111$ (one total pair) or $1111$ (two total pairs). The odds of $E_{n-3}$ being one is also 0.5, so we have $(2/8) + (1/8)*(1/2) = 5/16 = 0.3125$ per pair = $0.15625$ per event. This is incorrect, but certainly closer to the seemingly correct answer of $1/3$. I believe it's because one could apply the same logic ad-infinitum to the events before.... It's not immediately obviously to me how to recursively apply the same logic. In other words, we always have to check one more event in the past to see if it was a 1.
2. I tried using a state machine of sorts, looking at two events at a time. I came up with two states, A and B. A is the state where there are no pending 1s to pair, and B is the state where there IS a pending 1. So A has 00 => No pairs, go back to A. 01 => No pairs, goto B since we have a pending 1 that wasn't consumed by a pair. 10 => No pairs, goto A. 11 => Pair, goto A (No pending 1s since these two are a pair themselves).

   Then, B has 00 => No pairs, goto A. 01 => No Pairs, goto B (Pending pair). 10 => Pair, goto A. 11 => Pair, goto B (Since the first 1 paired with the previous 1, and the second 1 is now pending).

   This state machine appears to give odds of 3/8 (0.375 per pair, or 0.1875 per event).

So the second method overestimates, and the first method underestimates. I made the following Java code to simulate 1,000,000 events and calculate the proportion of "pairs" found.

```
public class TestPairs{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    
    int pairs = 0;
    int events = 0;
    boolean pendingPair = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        boolean eventWasOne = Math.random() < 0.50;
        
        if(eventWasOne && pendingPair) {
            pairs++;
            pendingPair = false; // Reset lastEventWasOne since '111' should not be considered two pairs. 
        } else {
            pendingPair = eventWasOne;
        }
        
        events++;
    }
    
    System.out.println((double)(pairs) / (double)(events));
 }
}
```

This code gives 0.16678 per event or 0.33356 per two events (Pair of events, really, but I want to avoid the redundant definition of pair). The simulation leads me to believe the true answer is 1/6 per event, or 1/3 per pair of events - but impossible to tell for sure.

Would anyone mind showing me the error of my ways and demonstrating how to address this recursive problem mathematically? Thanks!!

EDIT:

It took me some time to understand exactly why @lulu 's solution worked - the numbers were correct for $E_n$ but I couldn't quite understand the recursion. I wanted to explain how I eventually got it in case others are confused.

1. $E_n$ is the expected number of 'pairs' after n events.
2. On event n, we have to consider how many pairs we expect to see. It turns out we can determine this by only looking at the previous two expected pairs, $E_{n-1}, E_{n-2}$.

   A. Consider any series of events up to n, such as 10010011101000111001101. We have four possibilities for the two events
   preceeding the current event, namely 00, 01, 10, 11.

   B. If the preceding event was a 0, then no matter what we roll (1 or 0) for the current event, we CAN NOT make a new pair. Ex. Even if we rolled a 1, then xxxxxx001 and xxxxxx101 are not new pairs (The x's indicate 1 or 0 arbitrarily). Thus, we say that we want $E_n$ to be the same count as $E_{n-1}$ if the previous event ended in a 0. And the probability the previous event ended in 0 is $1-P$.

   C. If the preceding event was a 1, then we have to look further back to the previous event to see if it was a 0 or 1. So we have two possibilities for the previous two events assuming the last event was 1: 01 and 11. If the last two were 01, that means we CAN make a pair if we roll a 1. Ex. xxxxxx011.  But what about 11? This is where I was getting stuck, since 11 depends on how many 1s are in a row. For example, 111 means a new 1 makes 2 pairs. Whereas 1111 means a new 1 is still only 2 pairs. And this goes on, ex. 1111111111 is a new 1 a pair? It seems to force us to continue looking back forever. Turns out we don't have to.

   D. The key insight is that we can look at the count from two events ago, $E_{n-2}$, and we don't have to look at any further events. Consider two cases, one where we have an odd number of 1s in a row, and one where we have an even number. For odd, ex. 11111, we know that adding a new 1 makes an additional pair. But unless we counted the 1s, we don't know that. However, if we "steal" the 1 from the previous event - so 1111 1, and then we count the pairs in the first group (1111 is two pairs)... We can see that we can now just check if we rolled a 1, and add a pair to the result and we'll get the correct value of 3 pairs. IE. 1111 11 is 3 pairs. Okay, what about an even number of 1s? 111111 (This has 3 pairs). If we add a 1 here, we shouldn't get a new pair. Let's try the same technique - take the preceeding event and separate it. 11111 1. Now the previous group only has 2 pairs, but if we roll a 1 we get 11111(2 pairs) 11 ( 1 pair) and 2 + 1 is 3 which is correct since seven 1s is only 3 pairs.

   E. More generally, if we have an even number of consecutive 1s, then removing the final 1 from the group decreases the pairs by 1. If its odd, it doesn't change the number of pairs to remove a 1. Then we always add a pair if the current event is 1. This gives us exactly the correct number of pairs for the last two events being 11 regardless of how many 1s may have came before it - whether even or odd.

   F. Looping back to what if the previous events ended in 01. We can actually use the same technique as (E). Ex. 111101 -> 11110 1. Separating the last 1 doesnt EVER change the count on the left hand side because there was a 0 before the 1. And for the 01 case, we always want to add a pair if the current event is 1, so this is correct. The technique in mathematical terms is that there is a P chance the last event ended in 1 (Handles 01 and 11 for previous 2 events). If that happens, then we want $E_n = E_{n-2} + P$. We want $E_{n-2}$ because we're "chopping off" that last one and only considering the count as of two events ago, before the one preceding the current event existed. And plus P because P is the chance the current event will be 1. So its the count two events ago + 1 if we roll a 1, + 0 if we roll a 0.

   G. Bringing this all together, to get the total number of expected pairs at event n, we have to do a probabilistically weighted sum of the counts we could have. We have $E_{n-1}$ if the last event was 0, at probability (1-P). We have $E_{n-2} + P$ if the last event was 1, at probability P. So, $E_n = (1-P)*E_{n-1} + P*(E_{n-2} + P) = (1-P)*E_{n-1} + P*E_{n-2} + P^2$ which is where @lulu 's answer takes over.

Comment: I did not go through your attempts, but I have attached a solution based on regressions.  I think it should be possible to solve it via expectation...first do it just counting the expected number of $1's$ which are the start of a $11$ pair.  That overcounts, of course, so subtract the number of $1's$ which are the start of a $111$ triple, then add back those which start $1111$ and so on.  Note:  I did not think this through so I might have it wrong (or it might be right but not especially easy to compute).  Anyway, the regression isn't bad.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I actually did try this via recursion as well (forgot to include that attempt, and my post was already long enough to demonstrate I tried to solve it myself) but my formula was slightly off. I'm going to study the differences and see where I went wrong. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the variant in which a "pair" just means two consecutive $1's$, so that $111$ counts as two pairs, this problem lends itself to recursion.

Let $E_n=E_n(p)$ denote the expected number of pairs (in your sense) $11$ in a binary string of length (selected in the manner you describe) .

We distinguish three possible beginning sequences, $0, 10, 11$.  These have probabilities $1-p, p(1-p), p^2$ respectively.  Any sequence (of length at least $2$) is one of those followed by a shorter sequence and the total number of pairs (in your sense) is the sum (the start $11$ contributes $1$ pair, the other two starts contribute $0$).  Thus, for $n≥2$, we get $$E_n=(1-p)E_{n-1}+ pE_{n-2}+p^2$$

Of course $E_0=E_1=0$, regardless of $p$.

With $p=\frac 12$, the unbiased case, we can solve this explicitly as $$E_n=\frac {1.5n+(-.5)^n-1}9$$

For general $p$ the solution is $$E_n=E_n(p)=\frac {p^2((-p)^n+np+n-1)}{(p+1)^2}$$

It follows that:  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {E_n(p)}n=\frac {p^2}{1+p}$$

Comment: Isn't that recursion instead of regression? But otherwise nice answer!

Comment: @Ingix  Fair point...I tend to use the words more or less interchangeably in this sort of context.  But I think you're right, that "recursion" is more typical here.  I'll change it.  Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful solution, thank you @lulu! Indeed, the limit of En for P=0.5 does approach exactly 1/6 as n approaches infinity! I have to study this a bit more to see why my own approaches failed, but this approach does makes sense to me. Definitely a great tool to add to my kit!